# php5enmod mcrypt with Puppet

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, puppet

Another Puppet related question.

As part of my installation with Puppet, I'm installing: -

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- PHP5-FPM
- Nginx
- MySQL etc

As part of the PHP class I have the following: -

```
package {[
        'php5-fpm',
        'php5-mysql',
        'php5-cli',
        'php5-mcrypt',
        'php5-curl',
    ]:
    ensure => present,
    require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}
```

This part works fine. No issues.

Once the server has finished doing its thing, I'm able to run: -

```
php5enmod mcrypt
```

This, again, runs without issue and mcrypt is enabled in the php5-fpm installation. The problem is arising with the following code block.

```
exec { 'enable-mcrypt':
    command => 'php5enmod mcrypt',
    path => '/usr/sbin',
    require => [
        Package['php5-mcrypt'],
        Package['php5-fpm']
    ],
    notify => [
        Service['php5-fpm'],
        Service['nginx'],
    ],
}
```

I've tried running it in various incarnations, and there are no issues regarding syntax or dependencies for it to execute.

However, when I look through the debug information I'm seeing this: -

```
Debug: Exec[enable-mcrypt](provider=posix): Executing 'php5enmod pdo'
Debug: Executing 'php5enmod pdo'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Exec[enable-mcrypt]/returns: /usr/sbin/php5enmod: 233: /usr/sbin/php5enmod: expr: not found
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Exec[enable-mcrypt]/returns: /usr/sbin/php5query: 181: /usr/sbin/php5query: expr: not found
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Exec[enable-mcrypt]/returns: /usr/sbin/php5query: 203: /usr/sbin/php5query: find: not found
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Exec[enable-mcrypt]/returns: WARNING:
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Exec[enable-mcrypt]/returns: usage: php5enmod [ -s ALL|sapi_name ] module_name [ module_name_2 ]
Error: php5enmod pdo returned 1 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Php/Exec[enable-mcrypt]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: php5enmod pdo returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

I cannot make heads nor tails of it. It would almost appear that php5enmod is not seeing the argument that's being passed to it, hence the `WARNING: usage php5enmod [ -s ALL|sapi_name ]` etc...

I say this because if I run `phpenmod` without any arguments, that's the same error you get.

If anybody has any ideas, I'd be outrageously thankful.

Comment: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?60122-find-not-found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the correct way to do this (As referenced @BMW's comment) is to ensure that Puppet knows where the "find" command is before attempting to execute php5enmod.

My puppet configuration is below:

```
# Ensure Mcrypt is enabled
exec { "enablemcrypt":
  path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ],
  command => "php5enmod mcrypt",
  notify => Service["apache2"],
  require => Package["php5-common"],
}
```

As you can see, by adding "/bin", "/sbin", "/usr/bin" and "/usr/sbin" to the path parameter, puppet can now use the "find" command, which it seems to use internally when executing commands with arguments. php5enmod now runs correctly for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. It seems a little verbose, but the logic is sound.

Comment: I agree, however within the path parameter you would only need the path for find and the path for php5enmod. Alternatively I think you could just have the directory where find is installed and call php5enmod with its full path (eg: `/usr/sbin/php5enmod`)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get this to work as I would have liked. I'm unsure if Puppet is just not playing nicely with php5enmod, or whether there's some internal issues with php5enmod and the way it's being called by the Puppet scripts.

However, I did manage to manually create the symbolic link and restart the service with the following block of code.

```
file { '/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini':
    ensure => 'link',
    target => '/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini',
    require => [
        Package['php5-mcrypt'],
        Package['php5-fpm'],
    ],
    notify => Service['php5-fpm'],
}
```

Hopefully this helps somebody out in the future.